# Ionic 2 images popup (angular 2 dynamic binding)

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, I have some HTML that I am pulling from a server. I want that if the user clicks on an `<img />`, then it should show the image in a fullscreen popup.

How do I do this -- basically, adding a ng-click to all img tags in dynamically generated content? The only way I can think of is using jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `jQuery`, you can bind the event on the container of the retrieved `HTML` for example:

```
<div (click)="clickHandler($event.target)">
 <!-- retrieved HTML here -->
</div>

clickHandler(e: HTMLElement){
    console.log(e); // here is the element which has been clicked  
}
```

and if you want to open the image in the fullscreen popup you can use [FileOpener plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/) , and it will be opened in the native viewer